# checkSelfPermission returns PERMISSION_GRANTED in Android 10 but permission denied

Tags: android

I am calling `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")` on a directory returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Interestingly, `checkSelfPermission` returns `PERMISSION_GRANTED` but when I try to write to the storage, I get permission denied. **This happens only in API level 29**. In API 28 or less, everything works as expected. Why does `checkSelfPermission` return GRANTED but it is actually not granted?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And on Android 10 file paths outside of your App's private directories are worthless.

Going forward it is probably best just to use Media Store or Storage Access Framework

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared

The reason why is that permission is still used see see table https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage but only for the MediaStore API